# Next Word in Lexicographic Order

Tags: python, string, algorithm

**Problem**

There is a word given. We need to find the next word occurring in lexicographic order.For example, if word is `lkjihfg` then the next word would be `lkjihgf`.

This is a problem at **Hackerrank** that you can see [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bigger-is-greater).
The problem for reference:

> Complete the biggerIsGreater function in the editor below. It should
>   return the smallest lexicographically higher string possible from the
>   given string or no answer.

**My effort**

What i've tried was finding the maximum index(say `indx`) of word such that after it all the characters are non increasing.Then swapping the char at `indx` with the minimum char ahead that is greater than char at `indx`. Finally, reversing the string after `indx`.

**Code**

```
def biggerIsGreater(w):
    ww = list(set(w))
    indx = -1
    l = [ord(ch)for ch in w]
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i] < l[i+1]:
            indx = i
        else:
            continue
    if indx == -1:
        return "no answer"
    j = len(l) - 1
    for x in range(j,indx,-1):
        if l[x] > l[indx]:
            l[x], l[indx] = l[indx], l[x]
            break
    l[indx+1 : ] = l[len(l) - 1 : indx : -1]
    y = []
    for z in l:
        y.append(chr(z))
    ans = ''.join(y)
    return ans
```

The problem with this code is that it's not passing all the test cases because it's producing wrong results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about your solution is that it has a good time complexity - `O(n)`, where `n` is a size of the input string. That's why you don't have any timeout errors.

> The problem with this code is, however is not all the test cases are validating.

That's so because you've missed one important case in your loop below:

```
for x in range(j,indx,-1):
    if l[x] >= l[indx]:
        l[x], l[indx] = l[indx], l[x]
        break
```

Consider a case like `5 4 6 4`. So, your `indx` is `2` and because of your condition `l[x] >= l[indx]` you will replace `l[2] = 4` with `l[0] = 4`. This way, your next word in lexicographical order won't change and you'll get a wrong result `5 4 4 6` even though it must be `5 6 4 4`.

So, if you make your condition stricter `>` and not `>=` because you actually need a **LARGER** character from the left then the solution will be working correctly.

Hence, just change your condition to `>` :

```
for x in range(j,indx,-1):
    if l[x] > l[indx]: # fix the sign here
        l[x], l[indx] = l[indx], l[x]
        break
```

I tested your code with the fix and it passed all the tests.